# Change in Q factor on tuning external magnetic field in Electron spin resonance experiment

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, experimental-physics, quantum-spin, spectroscopy, cavity-qed

Does the Q factor of the cavity resonator show a dip at the resonant value of the external magnetic field while performing an ESR experiment?If so, what is the physical reason behind it?

Comment: Can you give a little more context, such as a diagram of a typical experiment or a link to a paper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When going through the paramagnetic resonance line, the sample *absorbs* microwave energy (and dissipates it). To make an acoustic analogy, this corresponds roughly to putting a mute inside your trumpet.

I'd like to recall that in CW X-band EPR, you first have to *make the microwave resonate* before you *make the spins resonate*.

Again, the resonator and the field modulation are instrumental *tricks* to amplify the ridiculously low EPR absorption.